# Cakephp : What is wrong with my pagiantion and routing?

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

I am using cakephp 1.3.X . I am experiencing some problem with url routing and pagination

My URL will look like

```
http://project.dev/search/hamburg/place:1
```

Below is my Routing code

```
Router::connect('/search/:slug/*', array('controller' => 'searches', 'action' => 'index'));
```

Below is controller where I am coming to the search page

```
$this->redirect(array('controller'=>'searches','action'=>'index','slug'=>$slugUrl,$query));
```

My problem is when I go to the next page ,that won't showing the **place:1** , just linking to **search/hamburg/page:2** ie. place is missing

My index.ctp paginator options are given below

```
$paginator->options = array(
                                       'url'=>array(
                                            'controller'=>'searches',
                                            'action'=>'index',
                                            'slug'=>$this->params['slug'],  


                                    ));
```

What going wrong with me. I've had searched a lot in cake articles , but nothing works for me. Please advise me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add.

```
     Router::connectNamed(array('slug'));
```

At the top of your router.php

Or define third pass param in your route, to pass slug.

```
      Router::connect('/search/:slug/*', array('controller' => 'searches', 'action' => 'index'), array('pass'=>array('slug')));
```

Update view

```
     $paginator->options = array('url' => 
       array_merge(array('slug' => $this->params['slug']), $this->passedArgs)
     );
```

Comment: What would be result if I use this , I don't see any change. But Slug is already coming , params is not getting

Comment: All answers to your questions is here http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/945/Routes-Configuration

Comment: Also at the bootom of http://book.cakephp.org/1.2/view/166/Pagination-in-Views you will find sample route with pagination, you need define what you are passing at the route, third param.

Comment: I've tested with your edited section  array('pass'=>array('slug') . It works like passes the slug ,but url for next page still comes like searches/index/hamburg/page:2/place:1 . I need this as search/hamburg/page:2/place:1 . Any hope?

Comment: hmm... should work, what happen if you add Router::connectNamed(array('slug', 'page')) or and array('pass'=>array('slug', 'page')) to the route?

Comment: Not worked. Can you tell me about the view file updates, anything I need to update with view file?

Comment: I don' know , what is happening to my cake , sorry nothing worked. Still showing the same url pattern